# Show Input Box on Check

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, checkbox

You can see in the paper form attached what I need to convert into a web form. I want it to show the check boxes and disable the input fields unless the user checks the box next to it. I've seen ways of doing this with one or two elements, but I want to do it with about 20-30 check/input pairs, and don't want to repeat the same code that many times. I'm just not experienced enough to figure this out on my own. Anyone know anywhere that explains how to do this? Thanks!

P.S. Eventually this data is all going to be sent through an email with PHP.

[image]

Comment: Since this isn't dynamic, why bother using JavaScript or jQuery? Just use an IDE to build the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your HTML :

```
//this will be the structure of each checkbox and input element.
<input type="checkbox" value="Public Relations" name="skills" /><input type="text" class="hidden"/> Public Relations <br/>
```

in your CSS:

```
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.shown{
  display:block;
}
```

in your jQuery:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function () {
  // our variable is defined as, "this.checked" - our value to test, first param "shown" returns if true, second param "hidden" returns if false
  var inputDisplay = this.checked ? 'shown' : 'hidden';
  //from here, we just need to find our next input in the DOM.
  // it will always be the next element based on our HTML structure
  //change the 'display' by using our inputDisplay variable as defined above
  $(this).next('input').attr('class', inputDisplay );
});
```

Have fun.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!...Couple errors: missing `.` before `attr` and also unneeded `}` after `inputDisplay`...so the line should be `$(this).next('input').attr('class', inputDisplay);`...I don't have edit privileges yet :) Note to admin: It said my edit wasn't long enough as well, but all that needed changed was adding a `.` and removing a `}`...can't help it the needed change was so small...thanks!

Comment: Edits made to reflect the issues you identified - apologize. Also, if you don't want to run into editing issues, make sure you edit the BODY and include something like **EDIT 1** Added missing \.\ and removed erroneous \}\ - I like to escape my edits.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a good idea at all.

Think of the users. First they have to click to enter a value. So they always need to change their hand from mouse to keyboard. This is not very usable.

Why not just give the text-fields? When sending with email you could just leave out the empty values.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  The paper form is flawed - why check a box to fill in a number?  Let the filled in number imply a check and a blank value imply no check.  Done.  If you *need* the check value to store in a database or somesuch, handle it on the backend.  Don't make me check a box so I am allowed to type a number.

Comment: You know, that makes sense. I guess I just got hung up on converting the paper exactly how it is. Sometimes you just over think things :)

Comment: Better yet would be radio buttons.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski Why's that? Don't use any of them!

Comment: Radio buttons corresponding to a value of 1,2, and 3 make sure your visitor can only put in the approved values with very little overhead, and the process of "fill one of these three bubbles to rate something" is very well understood.

Comment: Ah, I did not reed the whole text in the printed form :) I concentrated on the checkbox issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since your stated goal is to reduce typing repetitive code, the real answer to this thread is to get an IDE and the zen-coding plug in:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/21/zen-coding-a-new-way-to-write-html-code/

http://vimeo.com/7405114